# Is reconnection of mysql database possible in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, reconnect

I am very new in node.js. I just want to know that database(mysql) reconnection is possible in node.js?

I wrote the following code to establish the connection when database was down for a fraction of second:

```
var http = require("http");
var mysql = require('mysql');
var trn_nbr="";
var amount1=""; 
var db_config = {
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : '',
    database: 'realmoney'
};

var connection;

function handleDisconnect() {  
  connection = mysql.createConnection(db_config); 
  connection.connect(function(err) 
  {                                                             
    if(err) 
    {                                                           
      console.log('error when connecting to db:', err);
      //setTimeout(handleDisconnect, 10000); 
      handleDisconnect();                     
    } 
    else
    { 
        console.log("Now Connected");
        connection = mysql.createConnection(db_config);
        for (var i=0; i<1000; i++)
        {  
            connection.query("select tran_nbr,tran_amount from tranlog",  function(err, rows)
            { 
                if(err) 
                {
                    if (err.code !== "PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST")
                        throw err;
                    else
                    {
                        console.log('query error when connecting to db:', err);
                        //setTimeout(handleDisconnect, 10000); 
                        handleDisconnect();
                    }                               
                }
                else
                {
                    tran_nbr = rows[0].tran_nbr;
                    amount1 = rows[0].tran_amount;
                    console.log("tran_nbr:",tran_nbr);
                    console.log("Amount:",amount1);
                    //sleep.sleep(5);//sleep for 5 seconds
                }
            })           
        }
    }                                                        
  });                                                           

  connection.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('db error', err);
    if(err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST')
    { 
      handleDisconnect();                        
    } 
    else 
    {                                      
      throw err;                                  
    }
  });
}

handleDisconnect();
```

You can also tell what is wrong in the code to help me.

I used the following code to implement connectionpool but the piece of code is not working:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : '',
    database: 'realmoney'
});

exports.getUsers = function(callback) {
  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if(err) { console.log(err); callback(true); return; }
    var sql = "SELECT id,name FROM users";
    connection.query(sql, [], function(err, results) {
      connection.release(); // always put connection back in pool after last query
      if(err) { console.log(err); callback(true); return; }
      callback(false, results);
    });
  });
});
```

I have already install connectionpool module on my server. I am running node.js code on the Linux server. 
Can I reconnect the mysql database again when it was down for some seconds and up again without restarting the application in node.js

Comment: `for (var i=0; i<1000; i++)` isn't this querying 1000 times the same query?

Comment: @DanFromGermany- this line of code is added only for testing. I need to check when database is disconnected during the query execution how we can manage it

Comment: I'd use a [`connectionPool`](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#pooling-connections) instead of a single connection, allowing you to quickly take a new connection from the pool if one is dropped.

Comment: @DanFromGermany- Thanks for your comment. Do you have any sample code for connectionpool, which would be helpful for me? or how can I modify the my code to implement connectionpool for database reconnection

Comment: I already linked it: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#pooling-connections

Comment: @DanFromGermany- I edited my question and added connectionpool part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58170/discussion-between-amit-raj-and-danfromgermany).

Comment: Can I reconnect the mysql database again when it was down for some seconds and up again without restarting the application in node.js